# Glass Sitecore Service save object for multilist resulting in 'Item not in list' warning

Tags: glass-mapper, sitecore-client

I'm using `ISitecoreService (Glass.Sitecore.Mapper, Version=2.0.11.0)` to save a glass item defined like this in Sitecore.NET 6.6.0 (rev. 130111):

```cs
[SitecoreClass(false,"{3ACCADE1-C482-422C-9A22-3479C661B6AD}")]
public partial interface IAnnouncementInfoItem:ISitecoreItem        
{   
    [SitecoreField(FieldName = "Announcement Text",CodeFirst = false)]
    string AnnouncementText { get; set; }   

    [SitecoreField(FieldName = "Working Groups",CodeFirst = false)]
    IEnumerable<Guid> WorkingGroups { get; set; }       
}
```

I'm running into an issue with the MultiList (mapped as `IEnumerable<Guid>`) where each value shows up as "Not in List" even though the value is clearly in the source.

[image]

The Guids match up correctly with the items defined in the source. It even finds the names of the values correctly. The only difference I have found between the items saved through `SitecoreService` and those saved from Content editor is that the Guids are saved as lowercase values when saved from SitecoreService.
[image]

Has anyone ran into this issue before? It seems like there is some case sensitivity happening but not sure if this is a bug in Sitecore, GlassMapper or something else entirely.

**Update**

When saving the item I'm passing in some text and  a list of Guids:

```cs
public void SaveAnnouncement(Guid announcementId, string text, IList<Guid> workingGroupIds)
    {
        var announcementItem =
            _srcItem.AnnouncementsFolderItem.GetChildrenOfType<IAnnouncementItem>().FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == announcementId);
        announcementItem.AnnouncementText = text;
        announcementItem.Name = ItemUtil.ProposeValidItemName(text);
        announcementItem.WorkingGroups = workingGroupIds ?? new List<Guid>();
        using (new SecurityDisabler())
        {
            //wrapper on SitecoreServiceMaster
            _dependencies.GlassSitecoreServiceManager.Master.Save(item);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you show us your code where you're populating your `WorkingGroups` property and saving the item?

Comment: Are there template id and item id attributes for that model you are saving?

Comment: Can you try converting the Glass guid to upper case, I wonder if the tool that does check is case sensitive

Comment: @ASURA yes the templateId and itemId attributes exist on the model correctly. It does also save but there is just the problem with this particular field type

Comment: @MichaelEdwards Since I'm working with Guids and not strings I don't have the ability to specify casing for the save. I could potentially try changing the model to use strings and set uppercase GUID strings explicitly but I would rather leave the actual type in place if possible

Comment: Just test in the content editor by using raw values and manually changing the value. You can then see if the framework needs updating to use lowercase letters or not.

Comment: @MichaelEdwards Yes if I switch the raw values to the uppercase version of the GUID then the 'Not in List' disappears and it works correctly

Comment: @Rondel - Could you please try to override a method for .ToString() which converts your guid alphabet characters to uppercase and before you save the item call yourGuid.ToString() with the override that you just defined.

I believe you could also try Guid.ToString().ToUpper() without overriding anything

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar issue and it was originated by the Guids. The multilist fields should store IDs instead of Guids. You can do the following:

1. Remove all your selected items and add them manually.
2. Save your changes and verify your raw values are IDs.
3. Debug your solution and you will see that your items will be mapped.

If you are adding items programmatically, you should add IDs (new ID(Guid/string))

Comment: Changing the GlassModel to use IDs instead of Guids seems to have done the trick. Thanks!